# Receiving a 524 error in Chrome dev tools when server returns a 429 error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure-web-app-service, cloudflare, http-error

Just wondering if this is a "known issue" that possibly has some sort of workaround.

I have a Node.js, MongoDB Atlas, Azure web application and server side code intentionally returns a [429](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) when it exceeds a rate-limit I have set up.

However, it seems to be coming back to the browser as a [524](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003011431-Troubleshooting-Cloudflare-5XX-errors#524error), which seems to be a Cloudflare error.

I'm wondering if Cloudflare is somehow 'converting' the response from a 429 to a 524?

And, if so, how to work around this so that I can handle the 429 error on the client side as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User error.

I was returning a status code from Node.js with:

```js
res.status("429");
```

Changed it to the following and it seems to have resolved the issue:

```js
res.status("429").end();
```